# How do I let the user download a csv file generated from an sql statement in tkinter?

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, export-to-csv

I am working on an project in which I am producing a csv file via an sql select statement in my tkinter app.

However I am not sure how I am supposed to download the csv file through tkinter.

Here is my current code:

```
    # importing all files  from tkinter
    from tkinter import * 
    from tkinter import ttk
    import sqlite3
    import csv 
    
    from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
      
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('200x150')
      
    
    def save():
        connection = sqlite3.connect("Products.db")
        ProductCursor= connection.cursor()
        ProductCursor.execute("Select title,price from products")
        with open("out.csv", 'w',newline='',encoding='UTF-8') as csv_file: 
            csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
            csv_writer.writerow([i[0] for i in ProductCursor.description]) # returns a list of tuples describing the columns in a result set.
            csv_writer.writerows(ShopeeCursor)
        ProductCursor.close()
        files = [('CSV FILES','*.csv')]
        file = asksaveasfile(filetypes = files, defaultextension = files)
      
    btn = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Save', command = lambda : save())
    btn.pack(side = TOP, pady = 20)
      
    mainloop()
```

Right now the code is able to download a copy of the sql results into my local machine but how do I make it so that when the user click on the button, they can choose to save this file anywhere they like ?

Comment: And how is it relevant to SQLite?

Comment: Hi, the intended output which was listed in the code was to convert my data from sqlite3 to csv format through tkinter button. Apologies if this doesnt link to sqlite

Comment: Instead of apologizing, you need to remove the tag.

Answer (score 0):

about export sqlite to csv this code works for me:

```
def exp():
    inpsql3 = sqlite3.connect('sqlite.db')
    sql3_cursor = inpsql3.cursor()
    sql3_cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM table""")
    with open('MyCSV.csv','w') as out_csv_file:
      csv_out = csv.writer(out_csv_file)
      # write header                        
      csv_out.writerow([d[0] for d in sql3_cursor.description])
      # write data                          
      for result in sql3_cursor:
        csv_out.writerow(result)
    inpsql3.close()
```

you just need to have file with name (in my case) MyCSV.csv.

And about saving as, i think you need function `asksaveasfile()`, and GUI widget in tkinter for that is `filedialog()`, here is some example:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()
filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir='/', title='Save File', filetypes=(('Text Files', 'txt.*'), ('All Files', '*.*')))
textContent = "I'm the text in the file"
myfile = open(filename, "w+")
myfile.write(textContent)
# to test
print("File saved as ", filename)
```